# how to change the closest id's color

Tags: jquery, ajax

newbie question.

I had

```
document.getElementById('heart-color').style.color = '#ff748c';
```

But how do I change the color to the nearest id? Want to do something like this...

```
$(this).closest('id').attr('style','color:#ff748c');
```

edit: I have this in yii, so i copied a portion from browser

```
<?php foreach($product as $product): ?>
    //stuff
    <button class="heart-circle-prod heart-color " 
    style="color:#ff748c;z-index:1" product_id="6" onclick="getResponse(this, 6);"
    name="yt2" type="button"><i class="fa fa-heart" id="heart-color"></i></button>
    //stuff
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: .closest("id") doesn't make sense. Just select the id, there can only be one.

Comment: What is `this`?  `$(this).closest('id')` doesn't do what you think it does.  `.closest` searches all parent elements to see if any match the selector.  It does not search for the element that's *physically closer*, it searches all parents.

Comment: You mean the nearest element that has an ID set?

Comment: perhaps you have more than one element with the same id in which case you shouldn't you should refer to the element by its class name

Comment: What element are you looking for?  What does "nearest id" mean?  Nearest to what?  What does "nearest" mean in this context?  What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: Oh Thanks Rocket Hazmat. Sorry then I misunderstood what closest means. Yes.. nearest id. Sorry guys.

Comment: @jaime: What does "nearest id" mean then?  I still don't know what element you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, my jargon is confusing. I am new to this. Okay so I have a loop. Within it, there is a like/unlike button. All I want is to change the color of that button onclick.

Comment: Like this: `$(this).css('color','#ff748c');`?  Or is the element you are clicking on not the element you want to modify?  Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Thanks rocket hazmat for responding. That does not work. I've updated the post. Trying to change 'heart-color' onclick.

Comment: You are setting `id="heart-color"` in your loop.  You cannot do that.  IDs are supposed to be unique.  You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `id="heart-color"` in your loop.  You cannot do that.  IDs are supposed to be unique.  You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.

Don't use `id` here, use a `class` instead.

```
<?php foreach($product as $product): ?>
    //stuff
    <button class="heart-circle-prod heart-color " 
    style="color:#ff748c;z-index:1" product_id="6" onclick="getResponse(this, 6);"
    name="yt2" type="button"><i class="fa fa-heart heart-color"></i></button>
    //stuff
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then since the `<i>` tag is a *child* of your button, you can do:

```
$(this).children('.heart-color').css('color','#ff748c');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it to me and especially for being so patient with me. I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest('#name').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#heart-color").css({
   color: "#ff748c"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the adjacent element?

In which case you can do:

```
  $(this).next().css({
        color: "#ff748c"
     });
```